# I want to refresh google map in every 3 sec not entire page in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to refresh google map in every 3 sec not entire page.

Javascript code

```js
 
<script>
  // Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  var uluru = {lat: <?php echo $longitude?>, lng: <?php echo $latitude; ?>};
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call functions at regular times using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

For example:

```
function updateMap () {
    // Refresh your map data here.
}
setInterval(updateMap, 3000);
```

This will call `updateMap` every 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds).